# Can I use setupWithNavController and setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener at the same time

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an activity with BottomNavigationView with 5 items and fragment to show the pages, I set the NavController as following  :
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mBottomNavigationView, navController);

but there is one item in the bottom navigation in some Scenario will open another activity.

I tried to add setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener and handle it but, the navigation for the other items doesn't work.

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener use addOnDestinationChangedListener. 
    `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
     if(destination.getId()==R.id.menu_item_id){
      //navigate to other activity
     }
});`

Comment: what if i dont want to change fragment and just trigger some event