# BottomNavigation View OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is deprecated

Tags: android, android-navigation

I am trying out the Android's BottomNavigationView implementation as per [Material Design](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#using-bottom-navigation)

However, on the MainActivity code I am getting a warning that `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` is deprecated - see the below snapshot

[image]

Have tried get an alternative method to work with the BottomNavigationView but I cannot find it.

Looking for help from anyone with a way out but in the meantime I have matched my BottomView's menu items ids with the fragment destination ids and I successfully achieved Navigation but with a limitation of not being able to update my toolbar title with the Fragment's name.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just use the `OnItemSelectedListener` interface:

**kotlin**

```kotlin
bottomNavigationView?.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    // do stuff

    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
}
```

**Java**

```java
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
    // do stuff

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 19):

```
  binding!!.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener{
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.home_menu -> {
                openFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance("", ""))
                return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.deals -> {
                openFragment(DealFragment.newInstance("", ""))
                return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.history -> {
                openFragment(HistoryFragment.newInstance("", ""))
                return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.page_2 -> {
                openFragment(AccountFragment.newInstance("", ""))
                return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

Try this!!.

Comment: home_menu click perfect but when i clicked on deal/second menu icon color not changed why?

Comment: @Arbaz.in just return true;

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Bubble Navigation](https://github.com/gauravk95/bubble-navigation) insted of BottomNavigationView.

Bubble Navigation is a light-weight library to easily make beautiful Navigation Bars with a ton of  customization options.

[image]

Comment: Looks awesome though a third party lib.

Comment: Cool library that I haven't seen before.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution for Kotlin. Make sure to `return@setOnItemSelectedListener true`, this line of code change the color of menu items in your navigation view.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.firstId -> {
                // Write your code here
            }
            R.id.secondID-> {
                // Write your code here
            }
        }
        return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is now deprecate use setOnItemSelectedListener below some example -**

```
bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.bottom_m_home:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        break;
                    case R.id.bottom_m_reward:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        break;
                    case R.id.bottom_m_wallet:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        break;
                    case R.id.bottom_m_share:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        break;
                    default:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
                return true; // return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get `setOnItemSelectedListener` to work since I was also using `setupWithNavController` so I switched to `addOnDestinationChangedListener` and it worked.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
     if(destination.getId()==R.id.menu_item_id){
      //navigate to other activity
     }
})
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627862/11209037)

Answer (score 0):

Access the bottomNavigationView via findviewby id instead of databinding.

```
    val bottomNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
    bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            //do your code
        }
        true
    }
```